# Google Drive OAuth triggers origin_mismatch on some browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, google-drive-api

I'm developing an angular webpage who needs to use the google drive api for file picking and some of the users of the application are experiencing issues with google oauth.

It says origin mismatch, but the URI is configured well on the google developers console and most of the users can access. I couldn't reproduce the error for myself but here's the error message of one of the users that are experiencing this problem.

[Error message on Google Chrome Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhVdF.png)

The fact is that no google account can grant the authorization on the same browser in that computer, the issue didn't happen in a google chrome of another computer tested, neither different browsers on the same computer. And it's not just a problem of chrome because some of the users say that they are facing it on Safari Ipad. Any ideas?

Here's the code I used to get the authorization

```
window.gapi.auth.authorize(
    {
        'client_id': this.clientId,
        'scope': this.driveScope,
        'immediate': false
    },
    authResult => {
        ...
    }
)
```

Library script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

I used [this site](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to specify the url address in the 'Authorised Javascript origins' in your client ID in the Google Dev console.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for answering but I already found the problem. It was that some users were accessing the site using "www." and most of them aren't, the route including "www." wasn't specified there. I said the routes were well configured but I'm gonna accept your answer since you're the only one who tried to help